# ¿Hay alguna regla para el uso de artículos antes de nombres científicos?

Tags: sustantivos, artículos, animales, plantas

Leyendo artículos acerca de seres vivos, en ocasiones veo que el nombre científico se menciona sin artículos, a diferencia de los nombres comunes. En particular hablamos de "el perro", "la cucaracha común", "el samán", y en artículos académicos se habla de *Canis Familiaris*, *Blatta orientalis*, *Samanea saman*. Pero incluso en ocasiones he leído y oído acerca de **el** *Homo sapiens* (quizá por ser esta especie...). ¿Cuál es la forma adecuada de usar los artículos con los seres vivos?

Comment: Buena pregunta!  Me gusta más sin el artículo, pero no sabría cómo apoyar esa opinión.

Comment: No puedo imaginar que no haga falta un articulo para nombres cientificos. Es imposible no usar un articulo en español. También en el plural: los homo sapiens. Claro, estoy hablando de textos escritos o frases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encontré [un articulo](http://medicablogs.diariomedico.com/laboratorio/2007/07/04/deben-escribirse-con-articulo-los-nombres-cientificos-en-latin/) interesante que responde a tu pregunta.

Del articulo citado podemos extraer este párrafo:

> En español, todos los sustantivos tienen género gramatical: masculino,
>   femenino o, más raramente, neutro. Y en latín también. Usados en un
>   texto escrito en español, los nombres científicos latinos de género
>   femenino conservan en español el género femenino; y los de género
>   masculino o neutro en latín adoptan en español el género masculino.

Y también esta esta parte que me parece importante:

> El uso de artículo ante un nombre científico sigue las mismas normas
>   que para el resto de los nombres propios en español. Salamanca o
>   Madrid, por ejemplo, son nombres propios en español, pero eso no
>   quiere decir que no tengan género ni puedan ir precedidos de artículo;
>   sí lo llevan, por ejemplo, en usos especificativos, como cuando uno
>   habla de la Salamanca renacentista (mucho más hermosa, por cierto, que
>   la Salamanca moderna) o del Madrid de los Austrias.
>
> De igual manera, escribiremos «Escherichia coli puede causar
>   infecciones oportunistas» o «tratamiento para erradicar Escherichia
>   coli y otras bacterias de la microbiota intestinal»; pero «la
>   Escherichia coli enteropatógena es más frecuente que la
>   enterotoxígena». O escribiremos «en 1894, John Doe llamó a este género
>   Enterococcus, que no debe confundirse con el Enterococcus de la
>   nomenclatura bacteriológica actual».

En el articulo también se menciona al principio que la cuestión no esta regulada internacionalmente y es la tradición la que impulsa a que se consideren como nombres propios ([esto esta respaldado en este articulo de la RAE](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=fnCHzHWJpVgxkDLl)), y por lo tanto en la mayoria de los casos "no" llevan un articulo que los precede.

En conclusión, los nombres científicos en latín llevan un articulo que los precede de acuerdo al contexto y como se estructure la frase, el hecho de que no existan regulaciones especificas para estos casos nos permite tener cierta libertad en su uso, dado que su uso es enteramente basado en la tradición y no en una norma especial para cada caso.

Comment: No acabo de ver cómo respalda el artículo de la RAE el no uso de artículo con los nombres científicos. A mí me parece lo contrario, ya que escriben *el Homo sapiens* en él, sin mayor explicación ni puesta en contexto, cosa que sí hacen con los demás ejemplos del artículo.